# How to maintain same zoom level in pixels among different screen sizes and densities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an image of a map which is displayed in my imageview. My image size is 2572*1864 px
I want users to see the same "piece" of the map regardless of devices and densities - i.e. my default zoom level should represent same part of the image in px. How do I do that?

I tried the following - calculated that the dimensions of the image piece I want to show is 800px height, and set the default zoom level to -
zoomLevel = (devicePxHeight / 800)

But that does not seem to be working and I get different zoom level among devices

Any help appreciated

Comment: Can't directly help on your problem, just wanted to say that your logic is sane. Common pitfall: make sure devicePxHeight / 800 isn't a integer division. Use devicePxHeight*1f / 800 if it is.

Comment: Youre a saviour! would 1 up if I could or mark this as answer if it was

Comment: I made it into an answer, cause, you know, it might help people :) Certainly not because I'm a sad nerd who thinks rep is cool...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probable cause

```
devicePxHeight/800
```

is an integer division

Explicitly make it a floating point operation like so

```
devicePxHeight*1f/800
```